# Password generator with requirments- If all the requirments are true I want to print (password) and save on a text file. But i dont know how

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, passwords, generator

```
for c in password:
            if not any(c in password for c in symbols):
                return False
            if not any(c.isdigit() for c in password):
                return False
            if not any(c.islower() for c in password):
                return False
            if not any(c.isupper() for c in password):
                return False
            return
                print(password)
                f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
                f.write(password + "\n")
                f.close()
```

Comment: I'm building a password generator and I got stuck as I can't make it return the print and save the password to a text file. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid doing extra work when verifying that your password satisfies all requirements. In my example, I've looked at each character only once and am performing the required checks every time I look at a different character.

In the example you provided, you're actually verifying that every character meets your requirements for every character in the password O(N*N) - this is not recommended.

Lastly, make sure you understand what the password requirements are. It seems like your logic is incorrect when trying to verify that a character is both lowercase and uppercase simultaneously.

edit: The author clarified in comments that in order for a password to be valid, that password must have at least:

- one symbol
- one digit
- one lowercase character
- one uppercase character

```py
has_symbol = False
has_digit = False
has_lower = False
has_upper = False

for c in password:
    if has_symbol and has_digit and has_lower and has_upper:
        break
    elif c in symbols:
        has_symbol = True
    elif c.isdigit():
        has_digit = True
    elif c.islower():
        has_lower = True
    elif c.isupper():
        has_upper = True

if has_symbol and has_digit and has_lower and has_upper:
    print(password)
    f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
    f.write(password + "\n")
    f.close()
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Did you want to `return True` someplace as well?

Comment: I was just trying to answer the question being asked. @Perdix only mentioned printing and and storing the password if it satisfied the requirements.

Comment: I'm trying to use the code you wrote, but i don't fully understand it. I need to have at least one of each group of caracters in my password, but somehow this is validating all passwards even if the requirments are not met.

Comment: @Perdix Thank you for clarifying the requirements. I have updated my answer so that it now satisfies your criteria. Let me know if you'd like a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

> **you should take care about time complexity by avoiding unnecessary
> loops.**

**this will help you:**

```
from string import punctuation


def check_pass(password):
    return all([any(filter(str.islower, password)),
                any(filter(str.isupper, password)),
                any(filter(str.isdigit, password)),
                any(filter(lambda x: x in punctuation, password))
                ]
               )


def save_password(password):
    if check_pass(password):
        with open("demofile2.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(password)
        print(password)
    else:
        print('Not Accepted!')


# Test
save_password('1@cA')
```